# Unable to run C programs using any compiler

Tags: c, windows

I had to write code in C and run it for an assignment. Since this is the first time that I'm using C, I downloaded MinGW as a compiler and Code Blocks as an IDE. I had no problem compiling the code given by my professor but it never runs (this is a simulation for an M/M/1 queue). When I say it never runs, I mean that a command prompt like window pops up and nothing happens after that. Every time I close that window and try to compile the SAME program again, I get an error that says that permission to access the file has been denied.

I then deleted Code Blocks and tried running the program through command prompt but I have the same problem. I've now tried doing it using LCC-Win but nothing has changed. Another weird thing that happens when I run any program is that three instances of the .exe file of that particular program are in my processes under task manager. I then need to restart my computer to try compiling that same program.

I even tried running a simple Hello World program and I have the same problem!

I am currently using a Windows 7 32-bit system.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Try disabling the virus protection when you run

Comment: the prior versions of the programs are still running, kill them This will prevent the permission issue when you try to compile

Comment: Does Code Blocks include a debugger? Run the program using that and step through line by line to see where it goes wrong.

Comment: Check your logic carefully (or post the source here). You may have an infinite loop. (Although hard to imagine for a simple "Hello world."
Does the task manager show a high CPU usage?

Comment: @pm100 They never get killed. Absolutely nothing happens when I click on "end process".

Comment: The never get killed because the antivirus (especially Avast) is "analyzing it" try adding that directory to the safe zone or disable the antivirus while you are testing the applications

Comment: Disabling Avast worked. Thanks a lot!